# When I use internal testing link, browser redirects to beta version on Google play market

Tags: android, google-play-console, beta-testing

I have my app available for Opened Beta testing and Closed Internal testing.
Even though I use Internal test link, it redirects me to the beta version on Google play.

**Note**:

- I use internal test link like that https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/xxxxx. Not beta test link like that https://play.google.com/apps/testing/xxx.xxx.xxx
- Gmail I use is added to the internal-test list in Google Play Console as expected.
- Other users from the same list can see Internal test version using the same link. The problem is with one user.
- I already tried LEAVE THE PROGRAM button. After rejoin the problem remains.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I cleared the cache of Google Play app (CLEAR DATA button) and that helped - internal test link redirected to the correct app version on Google Play.

I think that happened because I used the same user before for Opened Beta testing. Though it's strange that leaving the program and rejoining didn't help.

Hope that will save someone`s time.

Comment: A cache on the phone probably. Leaving and rejoining doesn't affect the cache on the phone, only the one on the server.